# SwiftUI: How to run action when user releases screen from a longPressGesture?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a rectangle setup with a long press gesture (0.5 second duration), I want a code snippet to run when the long press gesture starts, when it hits the 0.5 second minimum duration, and when the user releases the screen. I am having trouble on how to run the code when the user releases the screen. My code right now sits in a UIView struct, but I would be willing to move it into a separate class.

Currently my code turns the rectangle to green when the gesture "ends" (hits 0.5 seconds). I want it to do that and then for example change it to blue when I release the screen. I have also tried to follow Apple's tutorial on adding interactivity with gestures.
Thanks!

```
Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(self.rectColor)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height, alignment: .topTrailing)
                        .offset(y:60)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if(self.timingImplement.isRunning){
                                self.timingImplement.stop()
                            }
                    }

                    .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                    .onEnded{_ in
                        if(self.timingImplement.isRunning == false){
                            self.timingImplement.reset()
                            self.timingImplement.start()
                            self.timingImplement.genNewScramble()
                            self.rectColor = Color.green

                        }
                        else{
                            self.timingImplement.stop()
                        }

                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

checkout this Apple example, this does this (and a few thing more you can learn ;)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures/composing_swiftui_gestures